# how to solve the socket connection?

Tags: c, sockets, winapi, tcp, ip

```
SOCKET s;   // Create a SOCKET for listening for
// incoming connection requests.
SOCKET new_socket;  // create a socket for accepting incoming connection
uint16 port =18001;  

void CreateSocket()
{
  int sin_size; 
  WSADATA wsa;
  struct sockaddr_in server, master;  // creating a socket address structure: structure contains ip address and port number


  printf("Initializing Winsock\n");
  if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsa)!=0)
  {
    printf("Failed Error Code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
    //return -1;
  }
  printf("Initialised\n");


  //CREATING a SOCKET

  if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
  {
    printf("Could not Create Socket\n");
    //return 0;
  }
  printf("Socket Created\n");

  server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.1");
  server.sin_family = AF_INET;     
  server.sin_port = htons(port); 



  //Binding between the socket and ip address

  if(bind (s, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
  {
    printf("Bind failed with error code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
  }
  puts("Bind Done");


  //Listen to incoming connections
  listen(s, 3);


  //Accepting the incoming connection


  sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

  new_socket = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&master, &sin_size);

  printf("\n I got a connection from (%s , %d)",
    inet_ntoa(master.sin_addr),ntohs(master.sin_port));
  closesocket(s);


  //new_socket = accept(s, NULL, NULL);

  if (new_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
  {
    printf("accept failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(new_socket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
  } 
  else
    printf("Client connected.\n");
```

I am creating a socket to accept a connection from the Master. When I see the traffic in the wireshark then it'sconnecting for the first time and the response will be sent as reset and later
the master will send and its repeating like this for some time. Why it is not connecting with the master for the first connect command ?
Wireshark output

> 1:request:    90  72.170764   192.168.0.1 192.168.0.2 TCP 18001 > 63789
>   [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=8 SACK_PERM=1
>
> 2: response :    91   72.172839   192.168.0.2 192.168.0.1 TCP 63789 >
>   18001 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65536 Len=0

Comment: I don't see a reset in your Wireshark output.

Comment: I din post the remaining traffic : it is sending a connect again and again!!! why is it like that ??

Comment: You should compelte your example code. What does the master look like? What does `closesocket()` do? Where are `s`and `new_socket`defined? This code cant be the code you test with, since it can not compile.

Comment: Sorry : I forgot to add in the code. Now i edited it.

Comment: please provide client code too, and display the server print statements.